# What is the most efficient way to locate rows where 3 columns are not null?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

My co worker asked me for help writing a query, and the question was this:

> How can I return all rows from a table where all three columns B, C, and D are not null and they all contain positive or negative numbers.

I quickly gave him the following where clause that he says satisfies what he needed but I cannot verify as I don't have access to that specific database. This is what I told him to try:

```
select * from table_name
where ( nvl(B,0) + nvl(C,0) + nvl(D,0) ) <> 0 ;
```

This was off the top of my head a couple days back but i saw it in my email again so now i'm genuinely curious, Is there some glaring obvious way that would be better to accomplish this that i'm missing?

Comment: So you don't want rows with a 0 value? (0 is neither positive nor negative.)

Comment: Correct @jarlh sorry for the lack of clarification, they will be either a number that is not zero or NULL

Comment: Then Gordon's first query is the way to go.

Comment: @jarlh I added some clarification, he would like to see rows ignored where all three columns are null but if one or two of them contain null values thats fine.

Comment: `where a <> 0 or b <> 0 or c <> 0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you need rows where some cols might be nulls but not all of them, try the following "where clause

```
where a <> 0 or b <> 0 or c <> 0;
```

that will get you any rows where at least one column is not null

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you can just use:

```
select t.*
from t
where a <> 0 and b <> 0 and c <> 0;
```

The `<>` filters out `NULL` values and zeros.

The question may be ambiguous and really be that the signs are all the same.  If so:

```
where (a > 0 and b > 0 and c > 0) or
      (a < 0 and b < 0 and c < 0)
```

Comment: Ah thank you so much, the signs do not all have to be the same my apologies for leaving that out.

Comment: Would this still return rows where some of the columns are null? We want rows where some columns a null but not all three.

Comment: @snydez . .. . Nope.  `NULL` in comparisons returns `NULL`, which is not treated as `true`.

Answer (score 0):

```
with t (b,c,d) as (
select null,null,null from dual union all
select null,null,1    from dual union all
select null,1,2       from dual union all
select 1,2,3          from dual union all
select 2,2,2          from dual 
)
select * from t where coalesce(b, c, d) is not null
```

Comment: This does not relate with the question about a specific table...

Comment: not sure if I understood. updated the where clause after seeing the comments by op in the previous reply.

Comment: I need to return rows where columns 2,3,4 are not all null. It is okay if one or two columns are null.